# Why does this keep saying it isn't a function?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const commandBase = require("./commands/command-base.js");

    const readCommands = dir => {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir))
        for (const file of files) {
            const option = require(path.join(__dirname, dir, file))
            commandBase(client, option);
            console.log("Passed.");
        }
    }
```

Basically, trying to make my own discord bot in JavaScript, using `Discord.js`, of course. But there's a problem. It keeps saying commandBase isn't a function when it is. This is even part of command-base.js:

```js
module.export = function(client, commandOptions) {
    let {
        commands,
        expectedArgs = '',
        permissionError = "You do not have permission to use or run that command.",
        minArgs = 0,
        maxArgs = null,
        permissions = [],
        callback
    } = commandOptions;

    if (typeof commands === 'string') {
        commands = [commands];
    }
```

I also tried removing function and just using =>, nothing worked. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? It just gives out an error saying that it isn't a function.

Comment: What's the type of `commandBase` and what does `console.log` output?

Comment: It's a typo. `module.export` should be `module.exports`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
// command-base.js
export default function () {...}

// other js
import commandBase from "./commands/command-base.js"
```

Comment: I don't think suggesting ESM is a good idea in this case. It's likely the toolset being used doesn't support it.

Comment: It says "`Cannot use import statement outside a module`".

Comment: @KazumaKiryu stick with require for the time being. Just make sure you've corrected the spelling mistake.